# javascript инициализация свойств объекта

Tags: javascript, объекты

Есть объект:

```
var Auth = {
    submit_counter: 0,
    $login_field: "",
    $passwd_field: "",

    Submit: function()
    {
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы (и где-то видел, в каких-то плагинах, нагуглить к сожалению не  удалось) инициализировать свойства более красиво, грамотно и лаконично, нежели каждый раз писать `Auth.$login_field = ..., Auth.$passwd_field = ...` и т.п.

Должно же быть какое-то решение, вроде такого

```
Auth({
    $login_field: "var",
    $passwd_field: "var"
});
```

Пробовал через создание экземпляра объекта `new`, но возникает ошибка:

```
TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Auth')
```

Подскажите, как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что вы ищите - это [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
var object = {};

Object.assign(object, {
    $login_field: "var",
    $passwd_field: "var"
})

console.log(object)
```

Так же есть [`Object.defineProperties()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties),
им можно определить не только значения самих свойств но настраивать их поведение

```js
var object = {};

Object.defineProperties(object, {
  '$login_field': {
    value: "var",
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true
  },
  '$passwd_field': {
    value: "var",
    writable: false,
    enumerable: true
  }
});

object['$login_field'] = "val"
object['$passwd_field'] = "val"

console.log(JSON.stringify(object))
```

Цитата из MDN о значении свойств второго аргумента `props`:

> ```
> configurable
> ```
>
> Равен true только в том случае, если тип этого дескриптора свойства может быть изменён и если свойство может быть удалено из
>   содержащего его объекта.
>   Значение по умолчанию установлено в false.
>
> ```
> enumerable
> ```
>
> Равен true только в том случае, если это свойство можно увидеть через перечисление свойств содержащего его объекта.
>   Значение по умолчанию установлено в false.
>
> ```
> value
> ```
>
> Значение, ассоциированное со свойством. Может быть любым допустимым значением JavaScript (числом, объектом, функцией и т.д.).
>   Значение по умолчанию установлено в undefined.
>
> ```
> writable
> ```
>
> Равен true только в том случае, если значение, ассоциированное со свойством, может быть изменено с помощью оператора присваивания.
>   Значение по умолчанию установлено в false.
>
> ```
> get
> ```
>
> Функция, используемая как геттер свойства, либо undefined, если свойство не имеет геттера. Возвращаемое значение функции будет
>   использоваться как значение свойства.
>   Значение по умолчанию установлено в undefined.
>
> ```
> set
> ```
>
> Функция, используемая как сеттер свойства, либо undefined, если свойство не имеет сеттера. Функция принимает единственным аргументом
>   новое значение, присваиваемое свойству.
>   Значение по умолчанию установлено в undefine

Answer (score 1):

Для этого существуют классы:

```js
class SomeObject {
  constructor(sc = 0, lf = '', pf = '') {
    this.submit_counter = sc;
    this.$login_field = lf;
    this.$passwd_field = pf;
  }

  Submit(n) {
    console.log(`submit on ${n}`);
  }
}

let obj1 = new SomeObject();
let obj2 = new SomeObject(10, 'Rusic', 'password');

console.log({
  obj1,
  obj2
});

obj1.Submit('obj1');
obj2.Submit('obj2');
```